# Can't add javascript to chrome extension html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to add some javascript coding to chrome extension popup. 
I'm using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        button {
          height: 30px;
          width: 30px;
          outline: none;
        }
      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="ShowButton"></button>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The file popup.js is in the same folder as the html file.

I get this error:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-n39xN31cyZtiXqcqzIa0nbASOdc/O6Jshi15mzpw5oA='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

This is my popup.js content:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    document.getElementById("ShowButton").value= url;
});
```

This is manifest.json:

```
    {
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "eRelatorio",
 "description": "Extensão para fazer o relatorio de jogo na plataforma S**ore!",
 "version": "1.0",
 "author": "GoodReferee",
"browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Have a good day",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
 "icons": { "128": "icon.png" },
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
  "newtab": "newtab.html"
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
 "permissions": ["activeTab","tabs"],
 "permissions": [
    "https://www.google.com/"
  ]
}
```

This the error image:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Your code ***should*** work as expected... Your error reports that you can't have script written directly to the HTML file, but you haven't at all.

Comment: can you share the manifest.json file

Comment: You don't need content_security_policy at all here. The error message says you have an inline js code which means it's probably added by your full popup.js which you didn't show in the question. Simply don't add inline js code, use event listeners.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add code below to manifest.json

use unsafe-inline

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'",
```

Comment: change my answer @FábioAraújo